# How do I get the Ant <input> task to output åäö (and similar characters) properly?

Tags: ant, character-encoding

My first question. Please bear with me!

I have an Ant task that need to get some input from the user before proceeding. I use the [Input task](http://ant.apache.org/manual//Tasks/input.html) to achieve this. The input message will contain Swedish characters (eg å, ä and ö) but I am unable to get Ant to output the message properly. I'm testing this using the command line on a machine running Windows 7 Pro English (but obviously using a Swedish keyboard). Example:

```
<input message="åäö"/>
```

will output:

```
[input] Õõ÷
```

The build.xml is saved in UTF-8 format. If I do 'chcp' on the command line I get "Active code page: 850".

The same result can be seen when doing an [echo](http://ant.apache.org/manual//Tasks/echo.html):

```
<echo message="åäö"/>
```

will output:

```
[echo] Õõ÷
```

But in the case of the echo task I'm able to do:

```
<echo encoding="850" message=åäö">
```

to get the expected output:

```
[echo] åäö
```

The input task does however not have an encoding attribute and I'd very much prefer to not have to define an encoding at all, especially not on a per-task level (since I can't tell for sure on what machine the Ant script will be run from).

PS I have additional problems with the received input if it contains åäö and I set the input as a property that is later used in a filter copy task, but I guess that's a whole other question

Comment: IMO this is a good, non-duplicate and well formed question. Welcome Britzl!

Comment: Character encodings! Oh, how I hate them! (At least I'm on a platform that uses UTF-8 natively…)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can observe the issue on my Polish Windows.

```
<script language="javascript">
  java.lang.System.out.println("default charset: "
  + java.nio.charset.Charset.defaultCharset());
</script>
```

reports default charset as "windows-1250" while the console operates at "iso-8859-2" (I guess so).

Looks like `<input>` task uses the default charset thinking it would match the console input. In case it does not, I **managed to override the encoding** this way:

```
set ANT_OPTS=-Dfile.encoding=iso-8859-2
ant
```

In your case I would try to force `850`, as it looks like JRE defaults to something else.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/361975/setting-the-default-java-character-encoding) helped me to find the property name.

It is also important where `ant` is run from. If I run it from my ide, [jedit](http://jedit.org) console plugin, I don't need to override encoding, because I configured it to operate in `windows-1250`. So it seems to be another **workaround, using an IDE**.